# Datacenter to AWS over vpn or public latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, vpc

I'm trying to connect to my load balancer from my data center and I've two scenarios;

1. I've set up an internet-facing ELB on public subnets with 3 instances attached. Instances have private IPs only.
2. I've set up an internal ELB on private subnets with 3 instances attached. Instances have private IPs only.

On the second scenario, I'm using the VPN + Virtual customer gateway.

Somehow, on the first scenario, connection latencies are higher than the second one. Can someone explain to me what might be the reason?

As I know, VPN increases the steps (to encapsulate) while a packet reaches to destination.

Comment: I've created a simple nodejs application (simulates my real app) to send traffic to my ELB on every request and checks the connection time and report if it's bigger than 500ms. And run my load test tool to send a few hundred RPS. For the first scenario, it's dumping more reports than the second one. I've tested a few million times.

Comment: That doesn't work for the second because it uses a VPN (and tracert cannot show the vpn, as you know)

Comment: I can try with a few million trace*something tools but they are running on L4 but my VPN on L3 so it's not possible to trace VPN HOPS. 

BTW I use the Unix as well but tracert and traceroute does the same job by using different methods and types.